# Rails 4: display values for lookups

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, lookup-tables

I have a polymorphic `lookups` table that has columns `value` and `display_value`.  Similar to how HTML `select` form elements work, the `value` is what is stored in the DB while the `display_value` is what is shown on screen to make it look "pretty".

When there is no `display_value`, I want the lookups to default to the `value`. That way the code can always use `display_value` without running into `nil` errors, but only the `value` is actually required in the DB.

The following code resolves this problem, but it seems a bit "verbose" for something simple like this. Is there a cleaner or more concise Ruby/Rails method for coding this yet still conveying the intent?

```
# models/lookup.rb
class Lookup < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :type, presence: true
  validates :value, presence: true

  # If display_value present, display it or default to value
  def display_value
    value_to_display = read_attribute(:display_value)
    if value_to_display.blank?
      value
    else
      value_to_display
    end
  end
end
```

**update 2014-12-29 11:00**

It hit me just a few minutes after I asked this...

`read_attribute(:display_value) || value`

This is about as clear and concise as I can think of. Any better solutions than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you have is most succinct:

```
read_attribute(:display_value) || value
```

I think the following will also work if you keep the method's name `display_value`:

```
super || value
```

Also, since you ask for better solutions:

Do you really need to store the `display_value` value in the database?

I would just store the `value` in the database and create a `display_value` method that uses a constant.

For example:

```
class Lookup < ActiveRecord::Base
  DISPLAY_VALUES = {
    # add keys and values
  }

  def display_value
    DISPLAY_VALUES[self.value] || self.value
  end
end
```

But adding such methods in the model can soon create a clutter of view-specific methods. Such methods should be in helpers. Or decorators, if your app has them.

In simple words, a decorator is a class for each model; in this class you create view-specific methods such as your `display_value`.

But ignore all that in case you're storing `value` for say, an unaccented string, and `display_value` for exactly what a user inputs.

Comment: the reason for storing the display_value in the DB is so the text on-screen can change for users but the logic behind-the-scenes doesn't change. For example, users want to see "Administrator" instead of "Admin" on screen, but the logic in the code is the same. Storing them as a key/value is a viable option, but I want the flexibility of being able to change display_value without a code push (just update a DB record). I'm familiar with decorators, but since the display_value is closely tied to the record itself, I opted to keep it in the model since it is an actual column value.